# JavaScript bracket notation on object returning undefined on existing key

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key, brackets

**Summary**: Unable to access object key value using bracket notation as the *existing* key is returned as undefined.

I have an array of users (constructed by parsing a CSV files and its columns):

```
let users = [
  {
    '﻿User ID': '5ef62675b78d747c79086175',
    'Survey Completed Date': '11/12/19',
    'Survey Type': 'Assessment'
  },
  {
    '﻿User ID': '5ef62675b78d827c79086186',
    'Survey Completed Date': '27/12/19',
    'Survey Type': 'Assessment'
  },
  ...
];
```

For every user, I need to access their User ID in order to make a mongoose query.

```
  console.log(users) // Logs the above object

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

    const row = users[i];

    // Example with i = 0
    console.log(row) // {
                     //   '﻿User ID': '5ef62675b78d747c79086175',
                     //   'Survey Completed Date': '11/12/19'',
                     //   'Survey Type': 'Assessment'
                     // }
    console.log('User ID' in row)                         // false (??) <<<<<<<<<
    console.log(row['User ID'])                           // undefined (!?!)  <<<<<<<<<
    console.log(row['Survey Completed Date'])             // 11/12/19 (This works however)
    console.log(Object.keys(row)[0])                      // User ID 
    console.log(Object.keys(row)[0].trim() === 'User ID') // true 
    console.log(row[Object.keys(row)[0]])                 // 5ef62675b78d747c79086175 (want to 
                                                          //  avoid using this workaround since 
                                                          //  the properties will not always be 
                                                          //  in the same order)
    
    let userId = row['User ID']                           // (Still undefined)
    let user = await User.findById(userId);
```

I'm rather stuck. Any help or redirection would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(row)[0].trim() === 'User ID')` <-- why do you have `.trim()` there? Leading or trailing whitespace would explain the problem.

Comment: ...and in fact there *is* an invisible whitespace character at the start of the key.

Comment: Yes, you have a white space before U.

Comment: Special character that looks empty on browser - #ef bb bf (utf-8 character)

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra invisible whitespace character in keys of all of your objects (at least in those 2 you wrote). I started to copy-pasteing your `'User ID'` strings in console, and found out that in your data both `User ID` keys have this problem.

[image: pasted into browser console]

These invisible characters are rendered as red dots when pasted into my browser's console. I also checked 2 other keys in your data, and they seem to be clear; however, better do a `.trim()` on object keys when you form your data from a csv file.

FYI, the character that breaks your code is `\ufeff`, ["Zero-width no-break space"](https://unicode-table.com/en/FEFF/).

Answer (score 1):

when i copied your code before `"User ID"` there was one char with question mark and when removed it then `row["User ID"]` worked just fine. so please try it !

[in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-goodall-qe10r?file=/src/index.js) as you can see here it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

There's special character in front of `U` in `'User Id'`. Please try to run this answer. You will see it works.

```js
let users = [
  {
    'User ID': '5ef62675b78d747c79086175',
    'Survey Completed Date': '11/12/19',
    'Survey Type': 'Assessment'
  },
  {
    'User ID': '5ef62675b78d827c79086186',
    'Survey Completed Date': '27/12/19',
    'Survey Type': 'Assessment'
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  const row = users[i];
  let userId = row['User ID'];
  console.log(userId);
}
```